# Excel VBA 2016 - Trying to find name of checkbox, Unable to get value property error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Here's one that I'm stuck on.

I have a macro that opens all workbooks in a folder/directory one at a time, and performs certain actions, one of them is it unchecks every checkbox found in .Range("K25:U56"), but there is one checkbox in that range that I would like it to skip (or what I have it doing now is, store it's current value before the unchecking of all the boxes in the range happens, and then re-instate that value after all the unchecking happens, whichever). I receive "**The item with the specified name wasn't found.**" using the below line:

```
    ' Store checkbox50's value to return later
    Dim checkbox As Boolean
    If sh.CheckBoxes("Check Box 50").Enabled = True Then checkbox = True
    If sh.CheckBoxes("Check Box 50").Enabled = False Then checkbox = False
```

I've also tried:

```
    ' Store checkbox50's value to return later
    Dim checkbox As Boolean
    If sh.Shapes("Check Box 50").OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then checkbox = True
    If sh.Shapes("Check Box 50").OLEFormat.Object.Value = False Then checkbox = False
```

...and I get "**Unable to get the Value property of the CheckBox class.**" Here is a screenshot of what I'm working with (notice Check Box 50 as the name?).

[image]

Any ideas? If you want the full code posted, just leave a comment, but I'm wondering if there's a different way of searching for that one particular checkbox? Thanks!

Comment: If you loop over all of the checkboxes and print thieir names that might give you a clue

Comment: In one forum I read they listed the command as `sh.Shapes("Check Box 50").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value` and pointed out that object twice was not a typo. There was no explanation for why it was needed twice.

Comment: @TimWilliams I did try a loop to show a msgbox the all the box names in the range and I see it says "Check Box 50" when I do that. Ugh.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I did try that, but now it gives me the error "Object doesn't support this property or method"?

Comment: Is there a trailing space on it? Check the `Len` maybe?

Comment: @BigBen no trailing spaces either. It's very frustrating. Unfortunately I didn't make this spreadsheet, but I'm trying to make this tool for it. Basically I need it uncheck all the boxes except for that one I mentioned (50), the three to the left of it and the two above it. I guess I could just change the range I'm looking at to match that criteria, but I thought it would be easier to just ignore that one in the range by its name, because if the format of the sheet changes, that might pose a future problem. Ugh? lol

Comment: I just added 70 checkboxes to a sheet and had no problem accessing the 70th one. According to the error *something* is wrong with name... You checked the `Len` as well? Loop through all the checkboxes on the sheet, and `Debug.Print` the `.Name` and `Len(.Name)`...?

Comment: @BigBen You might be on to something, I've tried making a loop to return the Debug.Print names of all the checkboxes in the range into the immediate window, and I'm not getting anything. Is it possible the checkboxes don't even have names?

Comment: What do you get in the Immediate Window with `? Sheets("Yoursheetname").CheckBoxes.Count`?

Comment: @BigBen I'm having an issue trying to count the checkboxes in the range for some damn reason, but counting the entire worksheet I get 48 for a count, which is correct. 39 is the total number in the bottom half of the worksheet, and 9 in the top half. If that helps? Would it help if I posted the code? I have it commented well and it's not massive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193171/discussion-between-bigben-and-matt-wilson).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BigBen, we discovered the issue was because I was looping through all sheets in the workbook, but not every worksheet has a "Check Box 50" in it, so it was looking for something that didn't exist in those secondary sheets. I will work on my code to reflect this. Thanks!!!!